# Set default theme in Cloud9 to be monokai

Tags: cloud9-ide

I installed cloud9 in a ubuntu machine and I am trying to change the default theme of it.

In this file, plugins-client/ext.themes/themes.js, I changed from

```
defaultTheme : "ace/theme/textmate", //Default Theme
```

to

```
defaultTheme : "ace/theme/monokai", //Default Theme
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

The place you change is right, at least it worked for me.

```
"plugins-client/ext.themes/themes.js"
```

But I had to refresh browser session for it to work.
Close the browser and open again to trigger another session.
And, of course, restart the server node.